# Hour get's set to zero when parsing DateTime string

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a string based on a DateTime to be formatted differently. 
An example of the input is **2019-10-30 23**, the desired result would be **30-Oct-19 23:00:00** the output is **30-Oct-19 00:00:00**.

(DateString is the string containing the input)

```
string date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString + ",531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date.ToString();
```

Where is it going wrong with this slice of code?

Comment: Its because you use `.Date` this strips the time portion, remove that part so it will become this: `string date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString + ",531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [`.Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8) property, this is just the date portion and will strip out the time. The somewhat confusing thing about this is that you get a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) object back, but that's because we don't have a `Date` object.

Your new code would become:

```
string date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString + ",531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH,fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```